# Two Yahrtzeits One for Mother one for Father who comes First

Tags: tefilla, torah-service, kaddish, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, yahrtzeit

All other things being equal Halachically, if you have two people with Yahrtzeits one for a mother and one for a father, who has priority with regards to getting an Aliyah (and/or davening for the amud and/or saying kadish), and why?

Answer (score 7):

The halacha does not differntiate between one mourning for a mother or a father in terms of priority for any of the *chiyuv* davening activities. In fact, [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 26:16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34913&st=&pgnum=52) states that even one who is mourning for both a mother and a father does not get priority over one mourning for another relative.

Answer (score 1):

From sefer shraga hameir the one after the father has precedence. Since the father needs more zechusim in the next world since he had a harder time in this world. He has more mitsvot to keep and his yetser hora in sexual matters is a lot stronger like MZL which a woman does not have.

Comment: Can you explain what "MZL" is? There's a lot of yeshivish terminology, these days, and I guess this may be one of them? If this is a transliterated abbreviation for something, please explain this in English for the benefit of our non-yeshivish / Hebrew readers.

Comment: Believe that MZL was referring to משכב זרע לבטלה

Comment: @ChaninaChaim *motzee* not *mishkav*