# Women and girls covering their heads when lighting candles

Tags: candle-lighting, kippa-yarmulka, hair-covering, women

I'm not sure how widespread the following practice is, since, as a man - and even since I was a young boy - I have always taken little notice of other women and girls outside my immediate family as I (usually hurriedly) leave my home and go to Shul on Friday afternoons and 'Erev Yom Tov.  But I have observed, here and there, women who don't constantly cover their hair, as well as unmarried women and young girls, who specifically wear some sort of head covering when they light candles.

How widespread is this practice, and is it required (at least by some)?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29438/5

Comment: Similarly, related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29441/2091

Comment: I might guess it's a simple inconsistency (many if not most opinions say they should cover their hair inside their own homes), much like some men cover their head with a Yarmulke when they go to Synagogue even though they're supposed to wear one at all times.

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

The issue would seem to be covering one's head during prayer or blessings (in this case the blessing on the candles).

[Rabbi Adir Hakohen](http://www.ykr.org.il/Rabbi/22) of Yeshivat Kisse Rahamim quotes Rav Ovadiah z"l (Yabia Omer vol. 6 ch. 15) [here](http://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask/answer/1253) as holding that the custom today is for unmarried girls to not cover their heads during blessings, and they have halachic backing for this, but they should at least cover their heads during *Shemoneh Esreh* and *Birkat Hamazon*:

> שאף שהמנהג כיום שהבנות הרווקות אינם מכסות שערות ראשן בשעת הלימוד או שמברכות ויש להן על מה שיסמוכו, מ"מ לכל הפחות שישימו כיסוי על ראשן בתפלת שמונה עשרה ובברכת המזון.

(Note that the questioner [there](http://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask/answer/1253) was asking specifically about girls above the age of 12.)

Comment: Do the OP's women cover their heads for Shemone Esrei as well?

Comment: @DoubleAA Even if they do not, the OP's question is answered, for rather than engaging in mysterious activity, they are merely selectively following a halacha.

Comment: That's still a pretty mysterious thing to do, no? I question your assertion that this is actually _the_ halachic basis. It's a logical possibility, but a dubious one given how inconsistent people's practice is with its principles.

Comment: @mevaqesh Where in the Tanakh, is there support for a female covering her head or her hair when praying or reciting the name of HaShem?