# Kaddish: Men Before Women

Tags: tefilla, women, kaddish, men-male

Someone recently told me the Chida writes someone saying kaddish for a father has precedence before someone saying kaddish for a mother. Where is this Chida and what is the reasoning?

Comment: This is a more specific version of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8591/170 and should I think therefore be closed as a duplicate. Instead of asking about the Chida separately, you can offer a bounty on that question and specify that you're looking for what the Chida has to say about it.

Comment: @msh210 The OP *does* specify that he's looking for what the Chida has to say about it. He doesn't ask what one should do; he asks "where is this Chida and what is the reasoning".

Comment: 1. As the mother provides the needs of the body and the father of the soul. 2. Everywhere the father precedes the mother. Why is it special to Chida?

Comment: @AlBerko Interesting, thank you for sharing - On the contrary, this person told me it was based on the idea that women particularly have LESS spiritual lackings than men do since men are more likely at fault for not fulfilling the larger quantity of required mitzvos and would need kaddish to help men more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Yahrtzeits One for Mother one for Father who comes First](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8591/two-yahrtzeits-one-for-mother-one-for-father-who-comes-first)

Comment: If so, Gentiles are on a higher level than women and animals are the pinnacles of the creation. BS, Women represent the physical, the body, the form and men the spiritual, the essence, the soul. Gemmorah says the skeleton (white) comes from the father where the muscles (red) from the mother. Women have fewer Mitzvos as gentiles have still fewer Mitzvos, it is a scale. THat's why a sick man is called by his mother's name as the body sickness comes from there.

Comment: In addition, the soul of the woman is (thought to be) included with the soul of the husband, as we call Mr and Mrs. Berko. Woman takes her husband's name as the sign of her being a part of him, therefore a man also buys his wife, not the opposite.